# Was this scene in VOY: 'Alliances' the inspiration for a similar scene in 'Star Trek Into Darkness'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-into-darkness

**WARNING: Spoilers for both *Voyager* 'Alliances' and *Star Trek Into Darkness***

In *VOY* 'Alliances', we see a scene where Janeway and a bunch of Kazon leaders meet together and are then attacked by a Trabe flying vehicle:

[image]

In *Star Trek Into Darkness*, we see the following scene:

I think anyone would agree there is quite a significant similarity between the two.  My question is: **Did this scene from *VOY* 'Alliances' at least partly inspire the other scene in *Star Trek Into Darkness*?**

Comment: did the writers actually watch startrek before making the new movies? :P (side note, i like the new movies)

Comment: @N_Soong: A very similar scene is in Godfather 3. Let's hope there is some original writing in the next move.

Comment: I highly doubt the people behind Into Darkness ever watched or even read about Star Trek TV series

Comment: I was also just coming here to say they were both probably inspired by The Godfather 3 https://youtu.be/Td8eEM9KDig

Comment: Seems to have been discussed elsewhere on the internet https://dejareviewer.com/2013/09/24/movie-matchups-star-trek-into-darkness-vs-the-godfather-part-iii/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Very doubtful

First of all, there is no explicit public comment by any of the *Into Darkness* staff that connects this scene to *Voyager*.

More generally, director J.J. Abrams has said on a number of occasions that he is categorically not a Star Trek fan (although I'm sure he is a fan of his own work), and so his prior knowledge of scenes such as this would be limited.  On the other hand, writers Bob Orci and Alex Kurtzman are Star Trek fans, but of *The Original Series* almost exclusively.  In particular, they have not commented about any inspiration from the later series.  Finally, none of the production staff for *Into Darkness* overlap with *Voyager*'s staff.

It is hard to prove a negative, but combining all of this with the fact that Abramsverse Star Trek has distanced itself from Rick Berman-era Star Trek, and given that Paramount has seen *Voyager* and *Enterprise* as the nails in the coffin of that era, I suspect that any similarity with that *Voyager* scene is pure coincidence.

Comment: Probably the best answer we're going to get!  I know how hard it is to prove a negative. +1

Comment: @N_Soong : I agree.  I've searched extensively (before and after posting the answer) and can't find any statement that connects the two.  They may have a common origin, but I don't think one influenced the other, given the major disconnect between TNG-era Trek and JJTrek.  :-)